# Revert to previous material in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I place new material via

```
highlight(dbId, color) {
let viewer = this.viewer;

let myMaterial = this.createMaterial(color);

// used to rescale and remove the z-fighting
let scaleRatio = 1.005; // this was determined as optimal through visual inspection

var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;

var result = new Object();
result.dbId = dbId;
result.oldMaterials = {};

tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId,
    function(fragId) {
        result.oldMaterials[fragId] = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId);
        viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial);

        /* important technique if you want to remove z-fighting */
        let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
        fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
    },
    true);

viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
return result;
}

createMaterial(color) {

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    reflectivity: 0.0,
    flatShading: true,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    color
});

const materials = this.viewer.impl.matman();

materials.addMaterial(
    "MyCustomMaterial" + color.toString(),
    material,
    true);

return material;
}
```

Then I try to revert this to previous material via

```
unHighlight(dbId, oldMaterials) {
    let viewer = this.viewer;
    var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;

    let scaleRatio = 1.020; // this was determined as optimal through visual inspection

    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId,
        function (fragId) {
            const materials = this.viewer.impl.matman();

            materials.addMaterial(
                "MyCustomMaterial" + dbId + fragId,
                oldMaterials[fragId],
                true);

            viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, oldMaterials[fragId]);

            /* important technique if you want to remove z-fighting */
            let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
            fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
        },
        true);

    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

}
```

But it yielded no visible results. How i can revert to previous materials?
If I understand the logic of the Viewer correctly, it has material for each fragId of each dbId. And when calling setMaterial(), we replace the previous material with ours. And in order to return it, we must save the old material through getMaterial() for each fragId element and then return it through setMaterial(). But for some reason this approach does not work.

UPD:

I discovered a strange thing. When I save the data about it to the console before saving the material, it turns out that for one fragId several materials are specified.

```
    highlight(externalId, color, dict) {
    let viewer = this.viewer;
    var dbId = dict[externalId];


    let myMaterial = this.createMaterial(color);

    // used to rescale and remove the z-fighting
    let scaleRatio = 1.005; // this was determined as optimal through visual inspection

    var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;

    var result = new Object();
    result.dbId = dbId;
    result.oldMaterials = {};

    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId,
        function (fragId) {
            const previousMaterial = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId).clone();
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            console.log(dbId);
            console.log(fragId);
            console.log(previousMaterial);
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            result.oldMaterials[fragId] = previousMaterial;
            viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial);

            /* important technique if you want to remove z-fighting */
            let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
            fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
        },
        true);

    viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
    return result;
}
```

[image: Console log]

Answer (score 0):

Store a copy of the original material instead of referencing its entry in the fragment list - that would have been overridden with your custom material by the time you attempt to restore:

```
result.oldMaterials[dbId] = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId).clone();
```

Comment: Don't works.I discovered a strange thing. When I save the data about it to the console before saving the material, it turns out that for one fragId several materials are specified.

Comment: I wrote a UPD with a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the materials printed to the console are really different? When you copy a THREE object a new unique ID (uuid) would be assigned to the clone which is perfectly normal.

Comment: This is not the main problem. I need a working way to cancel highlighting without reloading the page.

Comment: Then the easiest way would be to use `viewer.setThemingColor` (see doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model)) and to clear them use `viewer.clear`(doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#clearthemingcolors-model)). Otherwise I can put together a working sample later for the issue with your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well as a temporary solution. But I also need to do the same things with the materials. I would be very grateful if you help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of approaches to tackle that.

The simplest one is as Bryan suggested, to use viewer.SetThemingColor - a good blog post can be found here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu;

However, the above approach works only on color level and not so helpful if you want more control on material features (like transparency).

Another approach is the one you took, where you create your own material and registering it in Viewer's MaterialManager (as you did).
In this approach, when assigning a material to a fragment, the old materials are not disappearing/overwritten, but are still available in MaterialManager along with your custom material (thus, cloning is redundant and in general works not so well with three.js materials).
From this perspective, to restore the material, is matter of reassigning the old material (a reference to which can be saved before assigning the new materials):

```js
highlight(dbId, color) {
  let viewer = this.viewer;
  let myMaterial = this.createMaterial(color);
  this.tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => {
      //save the reference to original material
      this.originalMaterial[fragId] = viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId);

      viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, myMaterial);
  });


  viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}


unhighlight(dbId) {
  this.tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => {

      if (this.originalMaterial[fragId]) {
          viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, this.originalMaterial[fragId]);
      }
  });
  viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```